# Update Table Contents on API Response

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm very new to React and although made some progress that I'm happy with, I've hit a snag that I'm stuck with and have been for over a day.

I'm creating a small app that uses React at the frontend and a .NET Core API server-side to supply the data.

So far, the following code works:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export class LGSRValidation extends Component {
  displayName = LGSRValidation.name

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { lgsr: [], loading: true };

    fetch('api/FormValidation/LGSR')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({
          lgsr: data,
          loading: false
        });
      });
  }

  static renderLGSRTable(lgsr) {
    return (
      <table className='table'>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Job Number</th>
            <th>Job Type</th>
            <th>UPRN</th>
            <th>Gas Register Number</th>
            <th>Service Date</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr key={lgsr.jobnumber}>
            <td>{lgsr.jobNumber}</td>
            <td>{lgsr.jobType}</td>
            <td>{lgsr.uprn}</td>
            <td>{lgsr.gasRegisterNumber}</td>
            <td>{lgsr.serviceDate}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }

  render() {
    let contents = this.state.loading
      ? <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
      : LGSRValidation.renderLGSRTable(this.state.lgsr);

    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <h1>{this.displayName}</h1>
          <p>This component demonstrates fetching data from the server.</p>
          {contents}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

What it quite simply does is call my API to return a single object to the client-side code and render each property within the object into a separate table column.

What I'm trying to do is introduce a button that `onClick` will call the API again, pull a new object and change the values in the table for the new property values. I'm happy with my server-side code and the creation of the random objects but my client side code is just not working.

I'm introducing the button within the parent  tags of the component like this:

```
render() {
  let contents = this.state.loading
    ? <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
    : LGSRValidation.renderLGSRTable(this.state.lgsr);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <h1>{this.displayName}</h1>
        <p>This component demonstrates fetching data from the server.</p>
        {contents}
      </div>


      <button onClick={this.getData}>
        Next
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Which seems to render fine. I'm also introducing a `getData` function like this further up:

```
getData() {
    fetch('api/FormValidation/LGSR')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            this.setState({
                lgsr: data,
                loading: false
            });
        });

    this.setState({
       contents : this.state.lgsr
    });
}
```

I suspect it's at this part where I'm going wrong.

Please can you advise how I can click my new button to call the API, return some data and pass the properties of the `lgsr` object into the corresponding table columns; replacing the previous data with the new data.

Comment: Trying to understand your requirements: You have a table with one data row. When the user clicks the button you want to replace the current data row with a new data row (of data received from the api) or do you want to add a new row to the table?

Comment: When you say "not working" what's happening?

Comment: @sn42 I'd like the new data to replace the old data. There should only ever be one row in the table; the button click will switch it out for new data.

Comment: @wdm Quite literally nothing happens. The API endpoint on the server is hit as expected but client side no error is thrown and the page also doesn't update. It's as if my binding isn't quite right between the rendered table and the new data set received from the button click.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to bind your `getData()` to your constructor so you can use `this` for your component rather than the current function.

`this.getData = this.getData.bind(this);`

A quicker way is to use arrow function like the following...

`getData = () => {....}`

This should hopefully fix your problem and allow you to use `this.state`

Comment: This did the job. Thanks ever so much @SGhaleb!

Answer (score 3):

I see 4 ways to improve your code:

1. Load data in the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method instead of the component's constructor ([more info](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html)). This should not be related to you problem but it's safer to ensure the component did mount before you possibly set the state.
2. As SGhaleb mentioned be sure that your `getData` function is bound, either using an arrow function or the bind alternative, otherwise `this.getData` is undefined and the button's `onClick` should be a no op. You could use `getData` for your initial request to not have duplicated code in your class.
3. In `getData` you set the state's `content` property, but you do it outside of the request's callback. It's value may be either the new or the old lgsr object of the new request. Check that you do want this or move it to the fetch callback.
4. Use a dedicated component to render the LGSR table instead of using a static render method and pass the required data via props to it. Again, nothing to do with your question.

Comment: Thanks for this sn42. @SGhaleb's answer fixed my problem but I'm going to try out all your suggestions now to improve my code. Alot of my existing code is straight out of the box from creating a new project in Visual Studio so it'd be good to learn how to do things properly using your advice

Comment: Thanks again @sn42. I just implemented all your suggestion and they worked great :)

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve here?
Can you paste your final code?

I see something terrible here. Your 'loading' is already declared in your component state and you're updating 'contents' state with the lgsr data. And in your render, you have declared contents as this.state.loading

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { lgsr: [], loading: true };

     /*some code here*/

    getData () {
        fetch('api/FormValidation/LGSR')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                this.setState({
                    lgsr: data,
                    loading: false 
               });
            });

        this.setState({
           contents : this.state.lgsr
        });
    }

      render() {
        let contents = this.state.loading
```